# populate @html.listboxfor using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-4, listboxitem

I use entity with db first in mvc4(razor)

**Requirement**:I have sp returning id and display name,
I need to display the names in @html.listboxfor
i used interface to get the details from stored procedure.When I get the result in the controller from stored procedure,I got struck in saving the result to listbox, 
I couldnt figure out how to store it in listbox.
I got struck in the controller code.Please help.

**Code:**

```
public class projService :Iproj
{
    project dbContext;

    public projService()
    {
        dbContext = new projectEntities();
    }

    public List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result> Getresorderdisplay()
    {
        List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result> oGetresorderdisplay = new List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result>();
        oGetresorderdisplay = dbContext.GetResourceOrderDisplay().ToList();
        return oGetresorderdisplay.ToList();
    }
}
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult testview()
{
    List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result> listboxdata = new List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result>();
    listboxdata = _Scheduler.Getresorderdisplay();
    ListboxViewModel objListboxViewModel = new ListboxViewModel();

    //struck with the follwing line.
    objListboxViewModel.resourcename=listboxdata ????

    return View(objListboxViewModel); 
}
```

view:

```
@model project.ViewModels.ListboxViewModel
@Html.ListBoxFor( m=> m.resourcename,Model.resourcename, new { @class = "resList",style="height: 462px;"})
```

model:

```
public class ListboxViewModel
{
    public string resourceid{get; set; }
    //listbox Values
    public List<SelectListItem> resourcename{get; set;}
}
```

**Edit:GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace proj.Data
{
    public partial class GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        }
   }
```

Edit2:
this is the error I'm getting after the update:
[image]

```
**Edit 3:**
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is transform the list data you have retrieved from the database into a `List<SelectListItem>` so it can be displayed.  The `Linq` `Select` method makes this pretty easy:

```
objListboxViewModel.resourcename =
    listboxdata.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.DisplayName,
                                                   Value = x.ID.ToString() })
               .ToList();
```

So what you set the `Text` and `Value` properties to will depend on what the definition of `GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result` looks like and what properties it has.  In the `Select` method the `x` represents a single element of the `listboxdata` list and is of type `GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result`, so you can access it's properties like `x.Property`.  The `Select` method constructed in this way will return a new list of `SelectListItem`.

Comment: thanks a ton. how to get the values to text and value from the sp,Also check my update.

Comment: @gs11111 Like this `listboxdata.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.DisplayName, Value = x.ID });`

Comment: I'm getting a error next to listboxdata :(. Pleasee check my update.

Comment: @gs11111 It's supposed to be `objListboxViewModel.resourcename` not `objListboxViewModel` that you're assigning the list to.

Comment: @gs11111 Oh, either change your model to be `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> resourcename{get; set;}` or add `.ToList()` after the `Select` expression, so `listboxdata.Select(...).ToList();`

Comment: It worked,Thanks a ton.
One last help,I need to select only one item from the listboxfor.How to change it in view?

Comment: If you only want one item to be in the list than you should restrict the list when it is created in the action method.  You can do this using the `.Where()` method.

Comment: Can you please give some more details as I couldnt figure out with the keyword ".where()".

Comment: @gs11111 Sure, an example would be `listboxdata.Where(x => x.DisplayName == "blah").Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.DisplayName, Value = x.ID });`

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, :( 
I dont get what to check in the displayname condition. Can you Please help in this after getting this much far.

Comment: @gs11111 When you said you need to select only one item, which item did you mean?

Comment: Listbox displays the Displayname, Now I could select multiple Displaynames.
My requirement is to select only one display name at a time..